# angular 4 with webpack to asp.net core sometimes VERY slow to start

Tags: angular, google-chrome

Most of the time when I make a change to an angular component, the result shows up immediately in the browser, or sometimes, obviously it shows an error.

But too often, restarting the app takes about 30 seconds even though it was built in under a second. Sometimes there is an error on the browser console which appears to be because it got tired of waiting for the app to load.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I sometimes have this issue too. Are there any external JS scripts you're importing?

Comment: Not that I have added. Apart from my own app development everything else  was in the initial project.